# Get Inerface Of Another IP/Site

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to get the network interfaces from any site or ip. For example I want to get googl's opening networks interfaces.

From example from my little code that I get the my network interfaces:

```
public class InterfaceLister {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {

        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = interfaces.nextElement();
            System.out.println(ni);
        }

    }
}
```

How can I do as like me (code of my network interfaces' scanning), but for another IP's . If it possible ?

THANKS

---

code is changed:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class InterfaceLister {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {

        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        InetAddress google = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
        NetworkInterface anotherInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(google);

        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = interfaces.nextElement();
            System.out.println(ni);

            //if (anotherInterface != null)
            System.out.println("google: " + anotherInterface);
        }

    }
}
```

some outputs....

```
name:lo (Software Loopback Interface 1)
google: null
name:eth0 (Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter)
google: null
name:eth1 (Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extension Adapter)
google: null
name:net0 (Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI))
google: null
name:wlan0 (Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter)
google: null
```

Comment: if you have a chance to run that code on one of google's servers than you can have a list of network interfaces on that machine. with any other java code you can not retrieve a remote machines network interface lists.

Comment: Have I not any way to get the opening networks interfaces of another server ?